# Twitter Bootstrap 2.x dropdown changes position

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

My bootstrap dropdown menu changes position after I select an item and redirect to another page. The first image shows the dropdown in proper position prior to selecting dropdown item. And the second shows the position of the dropdown after I've selected a dropdown item and redirected to another page. I select the second menu item and the dropdown appears underneath the first menu item. (I guess I need a 10 reputation rating to post images, so you'll just have to imagine it. Sorry.)

My code is below

```
                <div class="navbar navbar-static-top">
                <div class="navbar-inner">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="navbar navbar-static-top">
                            <ul class="nav">
                                <li id="liHome" class="active" runat="server">
                                    <a id="aHome" href="/home.aspx" runat="server">HOME</a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="liFindxxx" class="dropdown" runat="server">
                                    <a id="aFindxxx" href="/xxxbrowse.aspx" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" runat="server">FIND SOMETHING</a> 
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li id="liBrowsexxx" class="dropdown" runat="server">
                                            <a id="addBrowsexxx" href="/xxxbrowse.aspx" runat="server">Browse</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Action 2</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Action 3</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Action 4</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="divider"></li>
                                        <li class="nav-header">Header</li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">A Link</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Another Link</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>

                                </li>...
```

Comment: FYI...This menu is on a master page and I'm setting the class of the <li> to active server side. I found that if I do not change the class to active, then the drop-down menu does not change position. I sure would like to continue to set the active <li> server side, so still looking for assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i add a `active` class to li with id `liFindxxx` like class="dropdown active", or to a li from the submenu i don't find a problem.

When you remove the dropdown class from li with id `liFindxxx` you will get the results you describe. So make sure to add `active` to class tag and not overwrite it.

Comment: Bingo, Bass! I was actually setting class="active" in the code behind instead of class="dropdown active". Thanks so much!